# Redirect Without Changing URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-applications, web

I want to redirect to page url from image url.

i.e. `nevil120.herobo.com/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg`
     to
     `nevil120.herobo.com/index.php?image=free`

The redirection should happen but url should not be changed in browser. Url should remain as `nevil120.herobo.com/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg` and page should load.

How to achieve it through redirection rules of .htaccess?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Jonan not yet. I have changed .htaccess file content. because of last line, not able to open site even.  And 1 more thing, I wanted to redirect from image url to page url but in browser, image url should be shown only.

Comment: How is `Chrysanthemum.jpg` related with `image=free`? What is image name is `another.jpg`?

Comment: @NevilPatel if I solved your problem, please accept my answer. If not, please tell me what's wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$ [NC]    
RewriteRule RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ index.php?image=free [QSA,L]
```

this will redirect all images with the .jpg extension to `index.php?image=free`.
if you want `images/Chrysanthemum.jpg` to redirect to `index.php?image=Chrysanthemum.jpg` you could do:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ index.php?image=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Note**: the QSA flag appends any parameters from the original url to the new one. That means that if someone goes to `images/Chrysanthemum.jpg?image=dandelion`, the `$_GET['image']` variable will be dandelion. To still get the first image parameter (Chrysanthemum.jpg) you can use the following regex in php:

```
$image = preg_replace('/image=([^&]+).*/', '$1', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

or you can just remove the QSA flag